# Weird output in reading file in c++

Tags: c++, string, fstream, stringstream

> CHROMOSOME_IQ         AllQele
>
> CHXROMOSOME_IA    AlleSle
>
> CHRCOMOSOME_IZ    AllelCe

I am reading the above lines from file.

```
void test(ifstream*, string*, string*, string*, string*, string*);
void read_file(char*);
int main(int v, char** argv)
{
    if (v != 2)
    {
        cout << "Files missing";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // calling method 
    read_file(argv[1]);
}
void read_file(char* j)
{

    string line, TChr, TType1, TType2, tUnk, TInfo;
    vector<pair<string, string> > TName;

    char t_strand, t_offset;
    int t_loc1, t_loc2;

    ifstream fileH;
    fileH.open(j);
    int count = 0;
    test(&fileH, &TChr, &TType1, &TType2, &tUnk, &TInfo);

    while (!fileH.eof())
    {
        ++count;
        test(&fileH, &TChr, &TType1, &TType2, &tUnk, &TInfo);

    }
    fileH.close();

    cout << count << "\n";
}
void test(ifstream* h, string* chr, string* tt1, string* tt2, string* tUnk, string* Tinfo)
{

    string line;
    getline(*h, line);

    stringstream line_tab(line);

    getline(line_tab, *chr, '\t');
    cout << "The value is " << *chr << "\n";

    getline(line_tab, *tt1, '\t');
    cout << "The value is " << *tt1 << "\n";
}
```

The lines are three, however, I get output as 4. 
I cannot figure out, why this is happening.
eof should work perfectly, instead it gives mein null value in 4th iteration.

Output:

> The value is CHROMOSOME_IQ
>  The value is AllQele
>  The value
>   is CHXROMOSOME_IA
>  The value is AlleSle
>  The value is
>   CHRCOMOSOME_IZ
>  The value is AllelCe
>  The value is
>  The value
>   is AllelCe

Also, while passing file handle and line, I have to use `stringstream`, otherwise, I would not be able to read while calling function void test.

Comment: `while(!fileH.eof()` is only true after a read has failed, so you call `test` one time where all of the reads fail.  You might also consider using references rather than pointers.

Comment: `while(!fileH.eof())` is wrong. You need to make `test` return a *reference* to the input stream, and do `while(test(whatever)) {`.

Comment: @RetiredNinja 'while(!fileH.eof() is only true after a read has failed' is plain wrong

Comment: Please get rid of all pointers and use references, instead.

Comment: @DieterLücking Feel free to provide a better phrasing then, but that is the reason his loop runs an extra time with bad data.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I was spotting obvious things, only. Please write an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I Will get rid of pointers. 
But, why the loop is running an extra time?

Comment: @ Dieter Lücking
please help

Comment: If I am getting null in last for one string, 
why am I not getting null for second value?

Comment: @DeathMetal because the second value still holds the prior row's value. It hasn't been overwritten by anything at this time. Use your debugger and see it for yourself by stepping through your code.

Comment: @ StarPilot
thank you. 
Why I need to use `stringstream line_tab(line);` to read line in function test?
I tried reading it normally, but it threw me an error.